# gorm different column order and test failure

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

In my code, I have following model:

```
type ID uint64

type BaseModel struct {
    ID         ID        `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;autoIncrement" json:"id"`
    UpdateDate time.Time `gorm:"column:update_date;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"update_date"`
    CreateDate time.Time `gorm:"column:create_date;default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" json:"create_date"`
}

type Rollback struct {
    BaseModel
    PID   ID     `gorm:"index"`
    Table       string `gorm:"column:tbl_name"`
    RollbackRow string `gorm:"type:longtext"`
}
```

I am using `CreateInBatches` method of `gorm.DB` struct.

I have unit tests using go-sqlmock. In this model, only insert operations are performed.

```
func expectRollbackInsert(mock sqlmock.Sqlmock, tablename []string) {
    args := make([]driver.Value, 0)
    for _, val := range tablename {
        args = append(args, 1, val, sqlmock.AnyArg(), sqlmock.AnyArg(), sqlmock.AnyArg())
    }
    mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("INSERT INTO `rollback` (`payment_id`,`tbl_name`,`rollback_row`,`update_date`,`create_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)")).
        WithArgs(args...).
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(int64(len(tablename)), int64(len(tablename))))
}
```

My test cases are failing sometimes due to different order of `create_date` and `update_date`.

One such failure is

```
ExecQuery: could not match actual sql: "INSERT INTO `rollback` (`pid`,`tbl_name`,`rollback_row`,`create_date`,`update_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?)" with expected regexp "INSERT INTO `rollback` \(`pid`,`tbl_name`,`rollback_row`,`update_date`,`create_date`\) VALUES \(\?,\?,\?,\?,\?\)"
```

For my use-case, order of column does not matter in insert. How can I handle it in unit-tests to handle all the scenario?

Comment: I think you have very limited options here because `sql-mock` expects the exact query match, So you can do partial query match if number of columns and order of columns is not important and see if its inserting in `rollback` or other approach is you write custom matcher which checks the query how you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading sqlmock documentation [here](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock), I got the following workaround:

```
func expectRollbackInsert(mock sqlmock.Sqlmock, tablename []string) {
    args := make([]driver.Value, 0)
    for _, val := range tablename {
        args = append(args, 1, val, sqlmock.AnyArg(), sqlmock.AnyArg(), sqlmock.AnyArg())
    }
    mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("INSERT INTO `rollback`")).
        WithArgs(args...).
        WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(int64(len(tablename)), int64(len(tablename))))
}
```

I removed columns and values. In my case, I do not need to care about `create_date` and `update_date` field, hence it worked fine.